# MySQL Query JOIN returning 1 null field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two simple tables:

**user**

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|   uid    |     firstname     |     lastname     |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|   4000   |       Zak         |        Me        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

**user_role**

```
+----------------------------------------------+
|   rid    |       uid          |     oid      |
|----------------------------------------------|
|   5      |      4000          |     7000     |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

I am using this query

```
SELECT us.firstname, us.lastname, ur.oid
FROM user us
    LEFT JOIN user_role ur
ON us.uid = ur.uid
WHERE us.firstname = 'Zak';
```

My result is

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|     firstname     |     lastname     |   oid    |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|       Zak         |        Me        |  (null)  |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

What am I missing?  It has to be something simple!

**UPDATE**

Has to do something with the `WHERE` clause .. Because if left out, it returns all rows with `oid` included

Comment: Should it not be `ON us.iud = ur.uid`?

Comment: Found it. Look at your column names. you have `uid` and `iud`

Comment: @Siyual you beet me by 7s :)

Comment: That was a simple mispelling when creating my post .. It's correct in the DB :-)   Did you read my update?

Comment: Should be just join, not left join

Comment: If I use Just `JOIN` all fields come back (null)

Comment: @Lelio wouldnt change anything. Weirdly, the query works on my end.

Comment: @AlexandreTryHardLeblanc should work for me too but why a left join? It is a one to one relationship

Comment: @Lelio True, but the problem isn't the join. I can confirm it works on mysql 5.6. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1853b/4

Comment: what are the column types for uid on both tables? are they the same?

Comment: @NirLevy --  Correct ..  Simple mistake on my part!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow a process like this:

run this query

```
SELECT *
FROM user us
WHERE us.firstname = 'Zak';
```

If you get a result the Where clause is fine. So now you run:

```
SELECT *
FROM user us
    LEFT JOIN user_role ur
ON us.uid = ur.uid
WHERE us.firstname = 'Zak';
```

If yuo get no records then there is something wrong with the join. Could be that they have some unprintable characters and 4000 <>4000 as a result. So let's check that.

```
select * FROM user us where us.uid = 4000
select * FROM user_role us where us.uid = 4000
```

If one of then does not return a result then there is a data problem where one of the fields contains unprintable characters.

If the select * works, then try the original query again only add a few other fields from the user_role table such as the uid.  Then you can see if the join is working but the field is empty or if the join is wrong or possibly you are looking at the wrong field.

```
SELECT us.firstname, us.lastname, ur.oid, ur.uid
FROM user us
    LEFT JOIN user_role ur
ON us.uid = ur.uid
WHERE us.firstname = 'Zak';
```

It is also possible the join fields are different datatypes and some type of implicit conversion is messing them up. In that case you probably want to explicitly convert or preferably design your table so that they both use the same data type as they appear to be in a PK/FK relationship.

Comment: Hey this list of possible problems relates to many years of scratching my head trying to figure out why something that looks right didn't work. If I hadn't made such mistakes, I wouldn't now know what to look for,